Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, problem 7.F.13
I'm trying to solve the right inequality in the following problem (from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", problem 13 of section 7F):

Suppose $S,T \in \mathcal L(V)$ are positive operators. Show that
$$||S-T||\leq \text {max} \{||S||,||T||\}\leq ||S+T||$$

In the above $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional inner product space and the norm of a linear map $T\in \mathcal L(V,W)$ where $V$ and $W$ are nonzero finite-dimensional inner product spaces is defined as $||T||=\text {max}\{||Tv||: v \in V \text { and } ||v||\leq 1\}$ which is essentially the greatest singular value of $T$ without directly mentioning singular values. As a reference for the level of mathematics to be used in the proof here's the proof of the left inequality:
Assume $I$ is the identity operator and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S-T$:

The operator $||S||I-(S-T)$ is positive since
$||S||I-(S-T)=(||S||I-S)+T$ and the sum of positive operators is
positive. Thus there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to
which the matrix of $||S||I-(S-T)$ is diagonal with nonnegative
entries on the diagonal. With respect to the same basis the matrix
of $S-T$ has to be diagonal where the diagonal entries are the
eigenvalues of $S-T$. Hence $||S||-\lambda \ge 0$ or $\lambda \leq
||S||$.
By a similar argument $||T||I+(S-T)$ is positive and $||T||+\lambda \ge 0$ or $-||T||\leq \lambda$.

Combining (1) and (2) we have $-||T||\leq \lambda \leq ||S||$, therefor $|\lambda|\leq \text{max} \{||S||,||T||\}$. Since the greatest singular value of $S-T$ is the greatest $|\lambda|$ we have $||S-T||\leq \text{max} \{||S||,||T||\}$.
Thanks in advance.

Is there any issue with plagiarism in requesting solutions to classroom assignments?

@TedBlack I self-study these materials, there is no classroom and no assignment.

For any symmetric operator $S$ we have $\lVert S\rVert = \sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}|\langle Sv,v\rangle|$. Indeed, the inequality $\geq$ follows from Cauchy Schwarz and the other inequality is obtained by taking $v$ to be an eigenvector whose eigenvalue has the largest absolute values among all eigenvalues (this argument is perhaps the shortest in this setting, but not very nice as it does not work in infinite dimensions, see here for another argument). Note that for positive operators we may ignore the absolute values. Now for positive $S,T$ we have $\langle Sv,v\rangle\leq \langle Sv,v\rangle+\langle Tv,v\rangle$ and so $$\lVert S\rVert = \sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}\langle Sv,v\rangle\leq\sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}\langle (S+T)v,v\rangle =\lVert S+T\rVert.$$
Similarly $\lVert T\rVert\leq\lVert S+T\rVert$.
